# Print global pointer gives coredump

Tags: c, memory, global-variables

I wrote a simple program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int *time = 0;
int main(){
  printf("time = %u\n", *time);
  return 0;
}
```

This will gives me segmentation fault on x86-64. Could someone explain the root cause?

Comment: **Undefined Behavior**!!

Comment: But I thought I have initialize the value to 0. Could you elaborate root cause more systematically?

Comment: You're trying to dereference a `NULL`-pointer.

Comment: @dannycrane That's absolutely right, you've initialized the value of the _pointer_ to 0. Then, when you try to dereference it, an access violation occurrs since you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: note: and exactly the same would happen with a local variable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, why not?

Comment: note that a pointer should be initialized to NULL, not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the comments mention, you are dereferencing a pointer that is pointing into an area of memory that it should not be.

```
unsigned int *time = 0;
```

is declaring a pointer to an unsigned integer, and the memory address it is pointing to is address 0x0.  You are then dereferencing this pointer, which is a problem, because you are asking to read the contents at address 0x0, which results in a segmentation fault.  Perhaps if you elaborate more on what you are trying to do, we could give you some additional information on how to proceed, but I'm not really sure exactly what you are going for with the above program.

Comment: The null pointer is not *necessarily* address `0x0`. It's represented as `0` (or, more clearly, `NULL`) in source code, and it's very commonly implemented as all-bits-zero, but as far as the C standard is concerned it's just a pointer that doesn't point to anything.

Comment: I want to initialize the pointer to 0. I think I did the wrong way. One correct way: `unsigned int a = 0; unsigned int *time = &a;`, correct?

Comment: You probably mean you want to initialize the memory pointed-to to 0.  You can do this by `unsigned int * time = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)); *time = 0;`  Your way works as well, it just depends on what you want to do.  Your method is pointing to a position on the stack, where as my way is pointing to a location in the heap.

Comment: @KeithThompson,  in every C compiler that I have ever used (and there have been dozens) NULL is either a built-in or defined in a header file as '#define NULL ( (void *) 0)'  so, actually, it points to address 0x00000000

Comment: @user3629249: Yes, a null pointer is commonly represented as an all-bits-zero pointer value, but it's not required. `(void*)0` *converts* the `int` value `0` to `void*`; that conversion may be non-trivial. If the null pointer is represented as `0xFFFFFFFF`, then `(void*)0` will yield a pointer value represented as `0xFFFFFFFF`. See section 5 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).